# Facebook ads api failing for few accounts and not for all

Tags: python, facebook-ads-api

I am not sure what's happening in with Facebook ads API but it starts throwing me the below error. yesterday it was all fine. this error is only for few accounts like in for below `live_accounts` for 1st account it's not throwing me an error but for the second it's throwing an error.

**Error:**

```
raise fb_response.error()
facebook_business.exceptions.FacebookRequestError: 

  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/act_25XX93XXX763XXX/insights
  Params:  {'time_range': '{"since":"2021-04-24","until":"2021-04-24"}', 'breakdowns': '["publisher_platform","platform_position"]', 'action_breakdowns': '["action_type"]', 'level': 'ad', 'time_increment': 1, 'limit': 1, 'fields': 'adset_name,ad_name,campaign_name,account_name,impressions,account_currency,video_p25_watched_actions,video_p50_watched_actions,video_p75_watched_actions,video_p100_watched_actions,inline_link_clicks,spend,actions,action_values'}

  Status:  500
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request"
      }
    }
```

**Here is my code**

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
import pandas as pd
from facebook_business.adobjects.user import User
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
from google.cloud import storage
import os

start = '2021-04-24'
end = '2021-04-24'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token, api_version='v9.0')
me = User(fbid="me")
my_account = me.get_ad_accounts()
account_list = pd.DataFrame(my_account)
appended_data = []
live_accounts = ['21XXX478XXX279X', '25XX93XXX763XXX']
for i in live_accounts:
    print(i)
    act = AdAccount('act_{}'.format(i))
    async_job = act.get_insights(params={'time_range': {'since': start, 'until': end},
                                         'breakdowns': ['publisher_platform', 'platform_position'],
                                         'action_breakdowns': ['action_type'], 'level': 'ad', 'time_increment': 1,
                                         'limit': 1,
                                         },
                                 # is_async=True,
                                 fields=[AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.account_name,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.account_currency,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.video_p25_watched_actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.video_p50_watched_actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.video_p75_watched_actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.video_p100_watched_actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.inline_link_clicks,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.spend,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.action_values,
                                         ])
                                         
    results = []
    for item in async_job:
        print(item, type(item), async_job)
        data = dict(item)
        results.append(data)
```

I have tried passing `is_async=True` in the `get_insights` method but in return, it's just giving me only 8 rows which don't seem right.

please help.

Comment: This could very much be due to an outage on Facebook insights platform.
In order to reduce the amount of data, you could ask for a breakdown based on adsets/campaigns (using the level parameter), then for each of these assets you can get a breakdown by ad level to get the same results (but with smaller chunks of data)

Comment: @IdanBeker can you please share any example or maybe just code how you would do that

Comment: @IdanBeker the level is causing the issue here, while changing level to other valid enum {ad, adset, campaign, account} of level I am losing the adset name and ad_name, any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to ad level first, and then access Ad(< ad_id >).get_insights().

When you try to get the 'level':'ad' from AdAccount level - with many fields, it throws this error.

Example code:

```
res = []
for i in live_accounts:
    print(i)
    act = AdAccount('act_{}'.format(i))

    ads = act.get_ads(params={'time_range': {'since': start, 'until': end}})
    for ad in ads:

        ad_ins = ad.get_insights(params={'time_range': {'since': start, 'until': end},
                                         'breakdowns': ['publisher_platform', 'platform_position'],
                                         'action_breakdowns': ['action_type'], 
                                         'time_increment': 1,
                                         'limit': 500
                                         },

                                 fields=[AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.account_name,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.account_currency,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.video_p25_watched_actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.video_p50_watched_actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.video_p75_watched_actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.video_p100_watched_actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.inline_link_clicks,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.spend,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.actions,
                                         AdsInsights.Field.action_values,
                                         ])
        res.append(ad_ins)
```

Alternate way is using async like in this example: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/master/examples/async.py